# Can anyone name any big sites hosted on Hetzner datacenters?

Tags: linux, mysql

We are thinking of moving from Rackspace to Hetzner but the management guys are looking for practices of other big websites who are hosted with them.
Can you name any famous website hosted there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some of their customers at this link:[selected clients](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/unternehmen/referenzkunden)

Comment: Should I be worried that most of them doesn't ring a bell?

Comment: No. See, BIT websites (amazon, microsoft - yes, they are one of hte top destinations, facebook) do not host on shared hosting but run their own data centers or rent part of a data center. They have hundreds of servers.